# Getting the active application's name on first mouse click

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the name of the currently active application, only on the first mouse click in that application.

I mean: when I'm always on the same application I don't want to get the name of the application every time the user click in the application. My code does function very well, but it writes the application name on every mouse click.

How can I change it if I want to get the name of the application only if the user clicks in another application?

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetMouseHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetMouseHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd2 = GetForegroundWindow();
            StringBuilder windowtitle = new StringBuilder(256);
            if (GetWindowText(hwnd2, windowtitle, windowtitle.Capacity) > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(windowtitle);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString,
        int nMaxCount);
}
```

Comment: do not know the api. but i guess first you will get the window name and then can get the process that owns it

Comment: If you only want to recognize the change of the active form, wouldn't the [`WM_SETFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event better fit your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two obvious options. One is to keep your last seen title and surpress writing if the next title coming is [equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the last seen title.

```
static string lastseen = null;

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd2 = GetForegroundWindow();
        StringBuilder windowtitle = new StringBuilder(256);
        if (GetWindowText(hwnd2, windowtitle, windowtitle.Capacity) > 0) 
        {
            var title = windowtitle.ToString();
            if (!String.Equals(lastseen, title)
            {
               lastseen = title;
               Console.WriteLine(lastseen);
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

A second option is to keep a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of seen titles, adding new titles to the hashset, surpressing if one title is already found in the HashSet

```
static seen = new HashSet<string>();

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd2 = GetForegroundWindow();
        StringBuilder windowtitle = new StringBuilder(256);
        if (GetWindowText(hwnd2, windowtitle, windowtitle.Capacity) > 0) 
        {
            var title = windowtitle.ToString();
            if (!seen.Contains(title))
            {
               seen.Add(title);
               Console.WriteLine(title);
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```